# How to retrieve the first div of an HTML variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html

Here is my code :

```
var htmlVar= $("<div id=\"foo\"><div id=\"bar\">Content</div></div>");
var firstDiv= htmlVar.find("div").first();
```

This does not work as expected as the real first div "foo" is not taken into account. I wrapped my htmlVar into another div by doing this :

```
var htmlVar= $("<div>" + "<div id=\"foo\"><div id=\"bar\">Content</div></div>" + "</div>");
```

But this code is ugly and I am pretty sure there is some cleaner way to do this.

I would also like my code to always return the first div of an html var, whatever its structure. For example it should return the "foo" div for this case also :

```
var htmlVar= $("<html><body><div id=\"foo\">Content</div></body></html>");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
var first = htmlVar[0];
```

or

```
var first = htmlVar.get(0);
```

Comment: Seemed pretty amazing at first, but does not work with such a case :

var htmlVar = $("<html><body><span class=\"span-class\"><div id=\"foo\">Content</div></span></body></html>");

It will return the span, not the first div

Answer (score 1):

If you have an HTML document like you have in your last example, you can easily run: $('div:first') to get the first div on the page.

The reason your first example didn't work is because the find command looks below its current element.  Think of it like you are inside your house and you open the front door.  You tell a computer to find the first house it sees.  It will find your neighbors house since it is already inside your house and can't see itself.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: How do I execute such a method on a var, not on the document? (and thanks for the explanations, seem legit to me =)

Comment: $(htmlVar).find('div:first').  Wrapping your variable in $() will convert it to a jquery object and then you can do everything you would normally be able to do on the page for your variable.  Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried splitting it up?

```
var htmlVar = $('<div />');
var newDiv = $('<div />').html('Content');
htmlVar.append(newDiv);

console.log(htmlVar.find('div:first'));
```